# Logging from multiprocess docker containers

Tags: logging, nginx, process, docker

I'm using the nginx method of symlinking linking to /dev/stdout for any log files that I want to appear in 'docker logs', however this is not working.

I have tested this with a simple cronjob in /etc/crontab, if a symlink is present (pointing to /dev/stdout) it doesn't write anything (as far as I can tell), but if I delete the symlink and it writes to the file.

Also if I echo into /dev/stdout it is echo'd back on the command line however it isn't found in 'docker logs'...

Question: Should this work? (It seems to work with nginx). Else, how would I get logs from 'secondary' processes to appear in docker logs.

For ref:

Nginx Dockerfile showing the symlinking method: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a8b6da8425c4a41a5dedb1fb52e429232a55ad41/Dockerfile

Created an official bug report for this: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19616

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
#FROM quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest # For testing

ENV v="Fri Jan 22 10:08:39 EST 2016"

# Setup the cronjob
ADD crontab /etc/crontab
RUN chmod 600 /etc/crontab

# Setup letsencrypt logs
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/letsencrypt.log
# Setup cron logs
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/cron.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/syslog

# Setup keepalive script
ADD keepalive.sh /usr/bin/keepalive.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/keepalive.sh

ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/keepalive.sh
```

The crontab file:

```
* * * * * root date >> /var/log/letsencrypt.log
```

keepalive.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start cron
rsyslogd
cron

echo "Keepalive script running!"

while true; do

    echo 'Sleeping for an hour...'
    sleep 10

done
```

Comment: ... what's your question?

Comment: Ha... Thanks for that, see the edit!

Comment: I've given up on managing logs in containers, and instead try and feed as much as I can via logstash to elasticsearch. Whilst there's a bit of setup overhead, it's MUCH less painful overall.

Comment: Ok, just as an alternative then, do you have any references to that setup? Down the line I was going to be integrating an ELK stack anyway...

Comment: Does your "keepalive.sh" script run a cron daemon?

Comment: Yup, line 5 in keepalive.sh :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

End result is that the /dev/stdout for the cron job was pointed to the different device.

/proc/self/fd/1 and should have been /proc/1/fd/1 because as docker only expects one process to be running this is the only stdout it monitors.

So once I had modified the symlinks to point at /proc/1/fd/1 it should have worked however apparmor (on the host) was actually denying the requests (and getting permissions errors when echoing to /proc/1/fd/1) because of the default docker profile (which is automatically generated but can be modified with --security-opts).

Once over the apparmor hurdle it all works!

This said, after looking at what is required to be modified in apparmor to allow the required request I decided to use the mkfifo method as show below.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV v="RAND-4123"

# Run the wrapper script (to keep the container alive)
ADD daemon.sh /usr/bin/daemon.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/daemon.sh

# Create the pseudo log file to point to stdout
RUN mkfifo /var/log/stdout
RUN mkfifo /var/log/stderr

# Create a cronjob to echo into the logfile just created
RUN echo '* * * * * root date 2>/var/log/stderr 1>/var/log/stdout' > /etc/crontab

CMD "/usr/bin/daemon.sh"
```

daemon.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start cron
cron

tail -qf --follow=name --retry /var/log/stdout /var/log/stderr
```

Comment: Provided Solution /proc/1/fd/1 worked for me


But I have stucked at "permissions errors" and  could you please let me know  how did you resolve the docker profile modified with --security-opts?


(  getting permissions errors when echoing to /proc/1/fd/1) because of the default docker profile (which is automatically generated but can be modified with --security-opts).)

Need to know what  changes are worked for to get over these permission errors. A snippet of code would be helpful to understand.

Comment: What is the provided solution? You speak as if there is a solution anywhere in this answer, and you state that it worked, however, I do not see the solution anywhere. 

"End result is that the /dev/stdout for the cron job was pointed to the different device.

/proc/self/fd/1 and should have been /proc/1/fd/1"

What does this mean? There is no reference to "/proc/self/fd/1" anywhere else in this entire question answer thread.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it was mentioned in the comments, but for reference - I find the best solution to `docker` logging is generally rely on the 'standard' multi-system logging mechanisms - specifically `syslog` as much as possible.

This is because you can either use the inbuilt syslogd on your host, or use logstash as a syslogd. It has an inbuilt filter, but actually that tends to suffer a bit from not being flexible enough, so instead I use a TCP/UDP listener, and parse the logs explicitly - as outlined in ["When logstash and syslog goes wrong"](http://kartar.net/2014/09/when-logstash-and-syslog-go-wrong/)

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 514
    type => syslog
  }
}
```

And then filter the log:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
  }
}
```

You can then feed this logstash to elasticsearch - either on a remote host, local container or what I'm doing now is a `docker network` with a multi-node elasticsearch instance. (I've rolled my own using a download and docker file, but I'm pretty sure a standalone container exists too).

```
output { 
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "es-tgt" ]
   }
}
```

The advantage here is - docker lets you either use `--link` or `--net` to specify a name of your elasticsearch container, so you can just alias the logstash config to point to the right location. (e.g. `docker run -d --link my_es_container_name:es-tgt -p 514:514 -p 514:514/udp mylogstash` or just `docker run --net es_net ....`)

The [`docker network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/) setup is slightly more convoluted, in that you need to set up a key-value store (I used `etcd` but other options are available). Or you can do something like Kubernetes.

And then use `kibana` to visualise, again exposing the kibana port, but forwarding onto the elasticsearch network to talk to the cluster.

But once this is setup, you can configure `nginx` to [log to `syslog`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html), and anything else you want to routinely capture logging results. The real advantage IMO is that you're using a single service for logging, one which can be scaled (thanks to the networking/containerisation) according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was really after an answer that addresses the main concern of logging to /dev/stdout.

I think I may have that now though, just testing it

Comment: That's fine. You just make reference to it in the comments, so I thought I'd chip in.